# 500 (Internal Server Error) on index.php while Linking stylesheets and JS

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, hyperlink

```
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=3.8.1 500 (Internal Server Error) index.php:27
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/css/wp-auth-check.css?    ver=3.8.1 500 (Internal Server Error) index.php:36
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=3.8.1 500 (Internal Server Error) index.php:28
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=20131201 500 (Internal Server Error) index.php:29
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/css/buttons.css?ver=3.8.1 500 (Internal Server Error) index.php:31
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2 500 (Internal Server Error) index.php:572
GET https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.2.1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

while sample initiator in index.php is:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='https://Samplesite.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />


<script type='text/javascript' src='https://Samplesite.com/Mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

Do you know why we suddenly encounter this issue?
This causes the menu not working.

Comment: You need to log at your server logs and tell us what the internal server error actually is.

Comment: does `Samplesite.com` exists?

Comment: Does samplesite have ssl enabled correctly? Test by browsing to it

Comment: Check your index.php at line 27; Check your web server error logs...

Comment: The whole site is up running. We just noticed that the CSS and JS on the admin bar are not working. for the Web server logs, we don't received any error, just a warning "The AD FS Web Agent for Windows NT token-based applications encountered a serious error. The cookies that were presented by the client could not be validated.   

This condition occurs when a client presents well-formed cookies that are not valid. If the client is known to be a valid user, this error might be caused by a transient issue. For instance, trust properties (for example, certificates) may have changed recently...

Comment: @MarcoS I already checked on line 27 <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='https://Samplesite.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.css?ver=3.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: _“Check your index.php at line 27”_ – I don’t think that’ll result in anything, because this is just the browser console(?) output showing where the resources where embedded – the _error_ itself lies not in the index.php, but is triggered when the resources themselves are requested. @user2450064: I suppose these URLs get rewritten to go through some kind of minifying processor or something? Go look there for what problems it might encounter in processing the original files.

Comment: Of course you should check the source of index.php... Do you have access to your web server logs? They could be quite explanatory...